# Disable paging on an ASP.Net ReportViewer Control

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a ReportViewer control on an ASP.Net 2008 website, and for displaying a report in Local mode, I want to disable paging only while viewing on the website.  If a report is 21 pages long, I want the entire report displayed on the website as one 'page', while still paging when printing and exporting.

Thanks

-b

Answer (score 6):

Just found a solution:

Open the report definition (.rdlc file) and set it's `InteractiveSize Height` property to some usable value:

[image]

Comment: Apparently you can just set the values for InteractiveSize to 0 (VS2010).

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and finally went the 'old-school' way of:

- Create a new report
- Copy your design into this new report
- Don't apply any paging in the new report

I tend to think that once you have added pagination to a report, there is no way to remove it!